# python typing: How to inherit self type (with static typing)

Tags: python-3.x, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I want a child class to inherit its parents' methods which return `self`.  While doing so, the type-checker (mypy) by default keeps the return type the parent class.  I want it to automatically infer the child class as the return type.  For simple cases I found the following code to work:

```
import typing

Self = typing.TypeVar("Self", bound="Foo")

class Foo:
    def foo(self) -> "Foo":
        return self

    def bar(self: Self) -> Self:
        return self

class Bar(Foo):
    ...

# The naive implementation reports the type as "Foo".
# This is not what I want
reveal_type(Bar().foo())

# Using a generic `Self` type seems to work for simple cases
# Revealed type is 'Bar*'
reveal_type(Bar().bar())
```

This "solution" breaks down if I try to use a context-manager:

```
import contextlib
import typing

Self = typing.TypeVar("Self")

class Foo(typing.ContextManager):
    def __enter__(self: Self) -> Self:
        return self

class Bar(Foo):
    ...

with Bar() as f:
    # Revealed type is 'Bar*'
    reveal_type(f)

with contextlib.ExitStack() as cx:
    f2 = cx.enter_context(Bar())
    # Revealed type is 'Any'
    reveal_type(f2)
```

It works in the first case but not in the second.  I think this is because I
did not specify the type parameter of `typing.ContextManager`.  If I do though, mypy reveals both types as `Any`:

```
class Foo(typing.ContextManager[Self]):
    def __enter__(self: Self) -> Self:
        return self
```

As far as I understand, this happens because `Self` isn't bound to any concrete type at this point.  I am kind of lost right now, I did not find any way to make it work ... Is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'keeping the type correct'? Do you want to differentiate between child and parent methods?

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote the question badly.  I want - as seen in the first example code - that the inherited method returns the type of the child, not of the parent.  More specifically I want this to work with context-managers; the inherited context-manager should return the child type, not the parent type

Comment: I don't know what reveal_type does, but when I just use `type()` instead, I get the `Bar` class twice. That is the desired child class. Maybe the implemenation of reveal_type is flawed?

Comment: Oh, I see, I completely missed to mention this: The question is about static typing and type-checking using mypy.  `reveal_type()` is no "real" function, it is evaluated by mypy and used to print out the inferred type.

Comment: Can you do `class Foo(typing.ContextManager[Foo]):`?

Comment: Sadly not, because `Foo` is not defined at the time it is referenced in the square brackets :/ You also cannot use a forward reference (like `class Foo("typing.ContextManager[Foo]"):`) here, as that is not supported by the language ...